# Is there a way to work case insensitive with UITextChecker?

Tags: ios, nsstring

I need my app to check if a word entered by the user is actually a real word or not. For doing this i found the UITextChecker. I am using it to check for words like this:

```
UITextChecker *textChecker = [[UITextChecker alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *language = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode];
NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, [currentWord length]);

NSRange misspelledRange = [textChecker rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:currentWord range: searchRange startingAt:0 wrap:NO language:language];
if (misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound) NSLog(@"is a word");
else NSLog(@"is not a word");
```

This works fine until it comes to words that begin with an uppercase (and that are a lot of words in german :) ). The user is entering the text lowercase, so even if a word is actually a word it outputs "is not a word" because of it being lowercase.
I found no solution for this problem in the documentation, also i searched for it here. 
So my question is if there is any better way for doing this, than transforming the first letter into an uppercase if the check failed?

Example for what i would do if there is no other way:

```
NSRange misspelledRange = [textChecker rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:currentWord range: searchRange startingAt:0 wrap:NO language:language];
if (misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound) NSLog(@"is a word");
else {
    NSString *firstLetter = [currentWord substringToIndex:1];
    NSString *restWord = [currentWord substringFromIndex:1];

    currentWord = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [firstLetter capitalizedString], restWord];

    NSRange misspelledRange = [textChecker rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:currentWord range: searchRange startingAt:0 wrap:NO language:language];
    if (misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound) NSLog(@"is a word");
    NSLog(@"is not a word");
}
```

Thanks for your help!